# Como obtener el Código Generado luego de insertar un registro

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Mi caso es el siguiente:

Cuando inserto un registro el procedimiento almacenado me genera un código alfanumérico, el cual necesito obtenerlo para poder usarlo en un siguiente registro.

Mi procedimiento almacenado de inserción como ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y Mi código C# como ejemplo es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Como podría hacer para obtener ese Código auto-generado al insertar un registro (que no es identity) y guardarlo en una variable de un Dto o de una Entidad?

Nota: los códigos mostrados son de ejemplo.

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad, considera agregar tu código en formato texto, no como una imagen

Comment: Y si despues de insertar seleccionas el valor y lo regresas en tu sp? Digo ya que los valores que estas recibiendo son esos

Comment: 3 pasos: Copiar código, pegar código, formatear código. Los pantallazos se utilizan mejor en casos para mostrar errores. Gracias por la comprensión :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recomendaria analices

[[ADO.NET] - Campos Auto numéricos (Identity)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/01/adonet-parte-6-ejemplos-simples-campos.html)

en el titulo `Obtener Id desde Stored Procedure` explico justamente esto que estas preguntando

Para esto defines un parametro de `OUTPUT` y asignas el `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` luego del insert

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ContactoInsert

    @Id int OUTPUT,
    @Nombre varchar(50),
    @Direccion varchar(50),
    @FechaNacimiento DateTime

AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Contactos (NombreCompleto
                                  ,Direccion
                                  ,FechaNacimiento)
                              VALUES (@Nombre, 
                                    @Direccion, 
                                    @FechaNacimiento);


    SELECT @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()     

END
```

desde codigo defines los parametros

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_ContactoInsert", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter paramId = new SqlParameter("Id", SqlDbType.Int);
paramId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(paramId);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nombre", nombre);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Direccion", direccion);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FechaNacimiento", fechaNacimiento);

int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (rowsAffected > 0)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["Id"].Value);
}
```

especialmente el que usa

```
paramId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

donde podrias tomar el valor despues de ejecutar el procedure

Answer (score 0):

Yo he hecho lo siguiente para lograr algo similar a lo que necesitas.

1.- Agrega un campo Id(o el nombre que elijas) INT Identity (Autoincrementable)

2.- Puedes usar `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` que te devuelve el Id del Registro insertado en ese mismo contexto de tu Store Procedure.

Checa este ejemplo

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsMarca
@Descripcion nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [Marca]([Descripcion])

 VALUES (@Descripcion)

  DECLARE @IdInsertado INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY()   

 SELECT  Descripcion FROM Marca WHERE IdMarca = @IdInsertado   

END
```

Así con `SCOPE_IDENTIY()` recupero el Id del registro insertado y hago un `SELECT` del campo que necesito devolver.